# React Navigation Tab Bar Icon disappears when changing background color

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have a React Navigation project with a normal Tabbar. Now I want to change the Apps color to a darker Gray-Blue.
So this is my code:

```js
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{style:{backgroundColor: "#191720"}}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ?  <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ShuffleIconActive /> : <ShuffleIcon />}}  />
      <Tab.Screen name="Personal" component={PersonalScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

My Tab bar looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Great! Now I wanted to remove the font/label at the bottom of my icons
So I changed the code to this:

```js
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{style:{backgroundColor: "#191720"}}, {showLabel: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ?  <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ShuffleIconActive /> : <ShuffleIcon />}}  />
      <Tab.Screen name="Personal" component={PersonalScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

So I added `showlabel: false`! But now my Tabbar looks like this:

[image]

You see: the backgroundcolor is missing. Just gone :/

When I add `{showIcon: true}` tothe **tabBarOptions** my Tabbar looks like this:
[image]

:/

So than I thought: Why not change the the order of the attributes. But than the Tabbar looks like at the beginning

This would be the code:

```js
const HomeTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={ {showLabel: false}, {showIcon: true}, {style:{backgroundColor: "#191720"}}}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ?  <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}}/>
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ShuffleIconActive /> : <ShuffleIcon />}}  />
      <Tab.Screen name="Personal" component={PersonalScreen} options={{tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => focused ? <ChatBubbleIconActive /> : <ChatBubbleIcon />}} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

And this is the Tabbar:

[image]

So it seems like only the **tabBarOptions** would be registered. This is bad and how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an issue with using tabbaroptions (this is deprecated in v 6.x). Try using [screenOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/6.x/screen-options) instead with your desired attributes and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I am trying. Do you have an example for the background color of the tabbar?